# How to solve $\sqrt{6}\cdot x^4 - (\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2})x^2 +\frac{3}{2} = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quartics

Of course I could put this is mathematica/wolframalpha or use a formula, but I think in here is a trick how to solve it very simply, but I can't figure it out. Help/Hints very appreciated

$\sqrt{6}\cdot x^4 - (\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2})x^2 +\frac{3}{2} = 0 \Leftrightarrow $

$x^2(\sqrt{6}x^2-\sqrt{3}+ \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2})= -\frac{3}{2}\Leftrightarrow $

Comment: Hint: let $t=x^2$ and solve the quadratic in $t$, first.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Your comment was useful. Why'd you remove it?

Comment: @IanMiller I concur. Only caught a glimpse of the comment before it was removed, but I believe it hinted at noticing "by inspection" that $\sqrt{2} \,x^2 - 1$ factors out, which is indeed a good hint.

Comment: @dxiv I've written an answer combining your hint and his to solve the problem. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @IanMiller On the contrary, +1 for the trig thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Set $y=x^2$.
2. Find $y$, using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).
3. Solve for $x$, from $y=x^2$.

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Comment: So simple, thanks, now I can finally go to sleep in peace, will accept it later this day

Answer (score 5):

As there is no $x^3$ or $x$ term you can treat it as a quadratic in $x^2$.

Let $t=x^2$ as dvix suggested.

$$\sqrt{6}\cdot t^2-\sqrt{3}t-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}t+\frac{3}{2}=0$$

Then factorize as suggested by G.Sassetelli.

$$\sqrt{3}t(\sqrt{2}t-1)-\frac{3}{2}(\sqrt{2}t-1)=0$$

$$\left(\sqrt{3}t-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{2}t-1\right)=0$$

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\text{ or }t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Note: This makes me think the original question was trig related so it might have been useful to include your steps which let up to the equation you were trying to solve.

$$x^2=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\text{ or }x^2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$x=\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\text{ or }x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$$

Or with rational denominators:

$$x=\frac{\sqrt[4]{12}}{2}\text{ or }x=\frac{\sqrt[4]{8}}{2}$$

Comment: I think your last 2 t's should be named x instead, else I don't really understand it

Comment: Yeh. Corrected now. Bad copy and pasting on my part.